Unable to upgrade Cmake from 3.29.0 with Homebrew
I'm on macOS 10.14.6 Mojave and Xcode CLITools is in version 11.3.1.0.1.1576735732.
Theese can't be updated.
I have CMake installed with Homebrew under my home directory:
$ which cmake
/Users/vjorma/.brew/bin/cmake

$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.29.0

When I try to brew upgrade cmake, I get
==> Upgrading cmake
  3.29.0 -> 3.29.3
Error: The contents of the SDKs in your Command Line Tools (CLT) installation do not match the SDK folder names.
A clean reinstall of Command Line Tools (CLT) should fix this.

Remove the broken installation before reinstalling:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Install the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1 from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

I can do no such thing, I'm on a school computer with no administration privileges. Both CMake and the Xcode command line tools are working just fine, I use them everyday. I'd like to find a Hombrew-based solution and avoid building Cmake myself, because it takes so long.

If you have no admin privileges how did you install Homebrew?

Homebrew only supports a few versions of macOS, right now this means macOS 12 or higher. Either keep using the current version of cmake, switch to MacPorts or compile a newer version yourself.

Yes I'm used to getting the warning about Homebrew not being supported on this old macOS every time I use it. But it has worked for me and it was just three weeks ago that I succesfully installed CMake 3.29.0 with it with. Building CMake on a much more powerful Linux server took almost 2 days so it's almost out of question.

@rapsik Only you can know what changed on your computer between three weeks ago and now. But building cmake on an M1 Mac took 13 minutes, so even taking architectural differences etc. into account 2 days seem to be way too long.

@rapsik: You should consider making the change to MacPorts; you won't be disappointed.
